# Where to Get FedEx API credentials for JeremyDunn Laravel Pakcage

Tags: php, laravel, api, fedex

I integrated **FedEx** into my E-commerce project, which is built in Laravel, and if JeremyDunn is a super useful FedEx package,   but The problem I'm facing is I got `Authentication Failed Error 1000`  Where do I get these values from the developer portal?

```
$rateRequest-\>WebAuthenticationDetail-\>UserCredential-\>Key = "----------";  
$rateRequest-\>WebAuthenticationDetail-\>UserCredential-\>Password = "----------";  
$rateRequest-\>ClientDetail-\>AccountNumber = "----------";  
$rateRequest-\>ClientDetail-\>MeterNumber = "----------";
```

When I created a project under organization in the developer portal only the key and secret were there but where from I got the other two (**accountNumber** & **meterNumber**) values?

Comment: Once you login to FedEx, navigate to: https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/web-services/process.html#develop ... There is a button to: `GET YOUR TEST KEY` which includes a test account and meter number.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulT.
I got the account and meter number. but when I tested them I got this message 
 "Severity" => "FAILURE"
          "Source" => "wsi"
          "Code" => "0105"
          "Message" => "General Failure"
Any idea ?

Comment: Try again maybe? ... sometimes the development environment has issues, and unfortunately, that is a very general error.